# Macro for switch or pattern matching with an Enum

Tags: enums, julia

I would like to have some syntactic sugar for switching on an `Enum`. Of course, an `if else` block works as expected:

```
@enum Fruit apple=1 orange=2 kiwi=3

function talk1(fruit::Fruit)
    if fruit == apple
        "I like apples."
    elseif fruit == orange
        "I like oranges."
    else
        "I like kiwis."
    end
end
```

I could even do the following:

```
function talk2(fruit::Fruit)
    say = ["I like apples.", "I like oranges.", "I like kiwis."]
    say[Int(fruit)]
end
```

But I don't really like the approach in `talk2`, since it allocates a vector and is less readable. I tried the [Match.jl](http://kmsquire.github.io/Match.jl/latest/) package, but I can't seem to match an `Enum`:

```
using Match

function talk3(fruit::Fruit)
    @match fruit begin
        apple  => "I like apples."
        orange => "I like oranges."
        kiwi   => "I like kiwis."
    end
end
```

```
julia> talk3(apple)
"I like apples."

julia> talk3(orange)
"I like apples."

julia> talk3(kiwi)
"I like apples."
```

Of course, in the `@match` macro I could cast the `Enum` as an `Int` and match the `Int`, but that hampers the readability of the switch.

Is there a way to get **Match.jl** to work on an `Enum`? Or is there a macro from a different package that can switch on an `Enum`?

Answer (score 6):

This is perhaps the main reason to use types instead of enums.  Then dispatch handles this for you:

```
abstract type Fruit end
struct Apple <: Fruit end
struct Orange <: Fruit end
struct Kiwi <: Fruit end

talk(fruit::Apple) = "I like apples."
talk(fruit::Orange) = "I like oranges."
talk(fruit::Fruit) = "I like kiwis."
```

As https://pixorblog.wordpress.com/2018/02/23/julia-dispatch-enum-vs-type-comparison/ point out, this code is efficiently inlined by the compiler.

Comment: Interesting; did you by chance try a performance comparison between my and your methods (I don't have access to my julia here right now)? *side note:* I think that last line should read `fruit::Kiwi`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I actually did that intentionally because I was trying to mirror the effect of the last `else` in the code since it's not an `elseif`.

Comment: While it doesn't really answer the question, I think the code should be written that way.

Answer (score 2):

Although I actually like your `talk2()` function, I guess you could improve on readability by using a `Dict`:

```
function talk(fruit::Fruit)
    phrases=Dict{Int,String}([
        (Int(apple)  => "I like apples"), 
        # or: (1->"I like apples"), or: (1,"I like apples")
        (Int(orange) => "I like oranges"),
        (Int(kiwi)   => "I like kiwis")
    ])
   phrases[Int(fruit)]
end
```

alternatively:

```
function talk(fruit::Fruit)
    phrases=Dict{Fruit,String}(
        apple=>"I like apples",
        orange=>"I like oranges",
        kiwi=>"I like kiwis"
    )
    phrases[fruit]
end
```

**Note:** this means you wouldn't even need to declare a function, but could just rely on `phrases[fruit]` instead; this will however give "weaker" warnings, i.e. a "key not found" error instead of a "MethodError" (if you give it a `@enum Veg tomato=1`, for example), which may make debugging more difficult in the long run.

---

If you want to use `Match.jl`, I think you need to be evaluate a potential match on `::Int(fruit)`, not `::Fruit` (all three cases in `talk3()` are of type Fruit!), i.e.:

```
function talk3(fruit::Fruit)
    @match Int(fruit_int) begin
        1 => "I like apples."
        2 => "I like oranges."
        3 => "I like kiwis."
    end
end
```

or using the `string()` part of the `enum`:

```
function talk4(fruit::Fruit)
    @match string(fruit) begin
        "apple" => "I like apples."
        "orange" => "I like oranges."
        "kiwi" => "I like kiwis."
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Your second dictionary solution looks nice, though I think the performance of dictionaries for switching is not as good as `if else` blocks. Converting the `Enum` to a string in `talk4` looks syntactically closest to what I was looking for, though it seems to defeat the purpose of using an `Enum`. :)

Comment: I think performance-wise the `talk3()` code above should be fastest, but you should consider `using BenchmarkTools` to figure this out yourself using your own setup and code (I presume your real-life situation is *not about printing your love for various fruits* :-) )

Comment: @clbieganek, have you tested the speed to compare between `Dict` and `if-else` branching?  My guess is that `Dict{Fruit, String}` look-up would be very fast since it's a hash table versus sequential lookup in a series of `elseif`s.

Comment: There is a frequently linked discussion on google groups with a benchmark showing that `if else` is faster than `Dict`, at least for the example they were looking at. However, I can't find the link at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple switch macro specifically for `Enum`s. The code is heavily inspired by [Match.jl](https://github.com/kmsquire/Match.jl), and lacks the generality and error handling of `Match.@match`. My `@enum_switch` macro is implemented as follows:

```
import MacroTools.rmlines

# Assume the correct number of switches are provided for the Enum.
macro enum_switch(v, block_ex)
    block_ex = rmlines(block_ex)  # Remove `LineNumberNode`s from block quote
    pairs = block_ex.args
    ex = nothing

    for p in reverse(pairs)
        if isnothing(ex)
            ex = esc(p.args[3])
        else
            ex = Expr(:if, Expr(:call, :(==), esc(v), esc(p.args[2])), esc(p.args[3]), ex)
        end
    end

    ex
end
```

It can be used to define a `talk_switch` as follows:

```
@enum Fruit apple=1 orange=2 kiwi=3

function talk_switch(fruit::Fruit)
    @enum_switch fruit begin
        apple  => "I like apples."
        orange => "I like oranges."
        kiwi   => "I like kiwis."
    end
end
```

And we can see it works as intended:

```
julia> talk_switch(apple)
"I like apples."

julia> talk_switch(orange)
"I like oranges."

julia> talk_switch(kiwi)
"I like kiwis."
```

Now let's compare `talk_switch` to the other proposed approaches.

```
function talk_ifelse(fruit::Fruit)
    if fruit == apple
        "I like apples."
    elseif fruit == orange
        "I like oranges."
    else
        "I like kiwis."
    end
end

function talk_array(fruit::Fruit)
    say = ["I like apples.", "I like oranges.", "I like kiwis."]
    say[Int(fruit)]
end

function talk_dict(fruit::Fruit)
    phrases = Dict{Fruit, String}(
        apple  => "I like apples.",
        orange => "I like oranges.",
        kiwi   => "I like kiwis."
    )
    phrases[fruit]
end

abstract type AbstractFruit end
struct Apple <: AbstractFruit end
struct Orange <: AbstractFruit end
struct Kiwi <: AbstractFruit end

const APPLE = Apple()
const ORANGE = Orange()
const KIWI = Kiwi()

talk_type(fruit::Apple) = "I like apples."
talk_type(fruit::Orange) = "I like oranges."
talk_type(fruit::AbstractFruit) = "I like kiwis."
```

As intended, `talk_switch` and `talk_ifelse` produce the same lowered code:

```
julia> @code_lowered talk_switch(kiwi)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = fruit == Main.apple
└──      goto #3 if not %1
2 ─      return "I like apples."
3 ─ %4 = fruit == Main.orange
└──      goto #5 if not %4
4 ─      return "I like oranges."
5 ─      return "I like kiwis."
)

julia> @code_lowered talk_ifelse(kiwi)
CodeInfo(
1 ─ %1 = fruit == Main.apple
└──      goto #3 if not %1
2 ─      return "I like apples."
3 ─ %4 = fruit == Main.orange
└──      goto #5 if not %4
4 ─      return "I like oranges."
5 ─      return "I like kiwis."
)
```

Finally, we can benchmark the performance of the various solutions:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime talk_switch(kiwi);
  6.348 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime talk_ifelse(kiwi);
  6.349 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime talk_type(KIWI);
  6.353 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime talk_array(kiwi);
  103.447 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)

julia> @btime talk_dict(kiwi);
  861.712 ns (11 allocations: 704 bytes)
```

As expected, `talk_switch` and `talk_ifelse` have the same performance since they produce the same lowered code. Interestingly, `talk_type` also performs the same as `talk_switch` and `talk_ifelse`. Finally, we can see that `talk_array` and `talk_dict` lag far behind the top three performers.